# I try to make a member variable's delegate to the class which has this member, but it didn't work

Tags: ios, uitextfield, character

I am a new ios developer, I want to create a new class inherit from NSObject, and it reference a UITextField. it has a property "maxLength" which limits the characters length of the UITextField, then I make the UITextField's delegate as this class"self.textField.delegate=self", and implement the method "textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:",but when it didn't work, anyone can tell me why? thanks in advance 
the code is given below:

```
@interface TextEditor : NSObject<UITextFieldDelegate>
///limit the characters length in the textfield
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSUInteger maxLength;
///reference a textField
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField *textField;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end

@implementation TextEditor

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.textField==textField) {
        if (string.length==0) {
            return YES;
        }
        if (textField.text.length-range.length+string.length>_maxLength) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}


-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _textField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        _textField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        _textField.delegate=self;

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

In the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TextEditor *te=[[TextEditor alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 270, 200, 50)];
    te.maxLength=10;
    [self.view addSubview:te.textField];
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug it? did you set a breakpoint to shouldChangeCharactersInRange method? does it invoke?

Comment: You should use `stringByReplacijgCharadtersInRange:withString` to determine what the effect of the change will be and look at the length of that string, but first check your delegate method is being called as heximal suggested

Comment: Yes, I have debugged it. Just as BhagyaNivi said, the reason is that the TextEditor object  in the viewDidLoad is destroyed as long as I leave the method. I try to declared it as  property, it is solved. thanks all the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **TextEditor** object is declared as local variable inside the **viewDidLoad** method. This object will be destroyed as long as you leave the **viewDidLoad** method. The **TextEditor** object's scope should be maintained until the textField object is destroyed or removed from it's superview. To achieve this, we can make the **TextEditor** object as instance variable or property.

The code will be changed to

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    TextEditor *te;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   te = [[TextEditor alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 270, 200, 50)];
   te.maxLength = 10;
   [self.view addSubview:te.textField];
}
```

Comment: that's the reason as you said, the textEditor object is destroyed as long as the viewDidLoad ends. I declared it as property,  it is solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this way your delegate method will not get called. so confirm  this in your viewcontroller class and write define delegate method in your viewController.m

No need to do like this.

Second thing if you want custom class for textfield then you should subclass `UITextfield` not `NSObject`. This will add `UIkit` in your class also.

hope this will help :)

Comment: the second method as you suggested, I have tried. it can work. the problem is solved, thanks

Comment: you're welcome :) if you think this is helpful then accept this answer and upvote so other people having similar issue can use it. :)